# C++ cURL - how to upload a file by POST

Tags: c++, post, upload, libcurl

I'm trying to upload a file to my website, consider it's url is http://mywebsite.com/index.php

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 on Windows 8 and here's my code (main.cpp):

```
#define CURL_STATICLIB
#pragma comment(lib, "libcurl_a.lib")

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>

int main() {
    CURL *curl;

    struct curl_httppost *formpost = NULL;
    struct curl_httppost *lastptr = NULL;

    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);

    curl_formadd(&formpost,
        &lastptr,
        CURLFORM_COPYNAME, "sendfile",
        CURLFORM_FILE, "C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\uploadme.txt",
        CURLFORM_END);

    curl = curl_easy_init();

    if (curl) {
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://mywebsite.com/index.php");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPPOST, formpost);
        curl_easy_perform(curl); //here it crashes
    }
}
```

When I debug it, here's the output:

```
'TestUpload.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Users\User\Desktop\TestUpload\Debug\TestUpload.exe'. Symbols loaded.
'TestUpload.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'TestUpload.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'TestUpload.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'TestUpload.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ws2_32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'TestUpload.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\advapi32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'TestUpload.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\Wldap32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'TestUpload.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\normaliz.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'TestUpload.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcr120d.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'TestUpload.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcr120.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'TestUpload.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\rpcrt4.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'TestUpload.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\nsi.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'TestUpload.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcrt.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'TestUpload.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sechost.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'TestUpload.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sspicli.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'TestUpload.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cryptbase.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'TestUpload.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\bcryptprimitives.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'TestUpload.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\secur32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
HEAP[TestUpload.exe]: Invalid address specified to RtlValidateHeap( 01170000, 011931F8 )
TestUpload.exe has triggered a breakpoint.
```

I've looked on other topics but I can't find where my problem comes from. Do I need to rename main.cpp to main.c ?

**index.php:** http://pastebin.com/Zqqm1eJU

**Note:** This is not suposed to be a malicious program, it's just for testing.

Comment: Save the error codes returned from all curl calls. They may hint you a reason for the program crash

Comment: Your code example works fine for me under linux. The errors could be caused by improper linking. Try uncomment the 2 first lines and link to the static library by specifying file and location in the linker tab.